# Using Instr VBA with values with Commas

Tags: vba, search

I'm currently trying to compare the title of a chart to a search string. If the search string is in the title of the chart, I want to return `True`.

Currently, I'm using `Instr(target, search) > 0`

However, some of the titles in the charts have the string and a comma such as: `Daimler, International`

Because of the comma, the Instr doesn't find the string and doesn't run. How do I use Instr to only consider the letters and not the comma?

Comment: It might help to specify the start position of your search: `Instr(1, target, search) > 0`

Comment: I thought the default starting position was 1.

Comment: The default is 1, but sometimes I've found it helpful to include it anyway with `Instr`.  Whatever works, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize that commas were a problem for `instr`. If that is true, then you could do a `replace()` before doing the `instr`, like:

`Instr(replace(target, ",", ""), search) > 0`

Comment: They are absolutely not a problem for Instr. `?instr("Daimler, International","er, I")` returns 6 just as it should. It's not a comma problem, it's when you don't include letters that are there.